# How to parse json without [ ]

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to parse **json**, but I didn't find how to parse array from this structure:

```
{
"0": {
  "title": "\u0417\u041d: \u0415\u0432\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0439\u0446\u044b ",
  "date": "2011-11-26 14:33:00"
  },
"1": {
  "title": "\u041a\u0430\u043a\u0430\u044f ",
  "date": "2011-11-25 13:55:00"
  },
"2": {
  "title": "\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430",
  "date": "2011-11-25 11:15:00"
  },
"3": {
  "title": "\u0423\u0416\u0421\u041a ",
  "date": "2011-11-24 15:45:00"
  },
 "time": 0.03944993019104
}
```

Comment: You can't parse an array from this structure, as there is no array here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, the problem is you don't actually have an array. You have a series of dictionaries, keyed by index. The only way to do this is to iterate over each numerical key, and add its value to a list.

Here's some pseudocode to help you get started:

```
yourArray = new Array(yourJSON.keys.length)
for key in yourJSON.keys:
    yourArray.put(yourJSON[key], int(key))
```

You'll need to make a new array object whose length is equal to the number of keys. Then, put each of the values for each key at index `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing these as [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and then accessing it's values keys provided.

To be more specific:

```
  try {
    JSONObject foo = new JSONObject(youJsonString);
    foo.get(name)
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    //handle exceptions
  }
```